# Забрать элемент из массива хэшей

Tags: многопоточность, perl

Есть некий скрипт, хочу сделать его многопоточным.

Допустим есть некий массив хэшей содержащий

```
my %hello : shared;
print Dumper(\%hello);

$VAR1 = {
          'a' => '1',
          'b' => '2',
          'c' => '3',
          'e' => '4',
          'f' => '5',
          'g' => '6'
};
```

И некая функция которая, допустим, просто print'ом выводит элементы этого массива на экран.

Чего я хочу: Я хочу, запустить это как-то в, допустим, 2 потока. Я это вижу так: Так как массив расшаренный, запускаем в бесконечном цикле до тех пор, пока в массиве что-то есть нашу функцию которая просто "забирает" из него значение и что-то с ним делает.

Вопрос: как теперь это объяснить машине на perl'е и будет ли это вообще работать? :)

**UPD**

Вот как-то типа так, только чтоб потоки одинаковые действия не делали (Сейчас они просто поочерёдно выводят полностью каждый содержимое массива хешей):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use threads;
use threads::shared;

my $threads = 2;
my @threads;
my %hello : shared;

sub test {
  my $num=shift;
  print "+ Thread $num started.\n";

  foreach my $key (keys %hello) {
    print $key, $hello{$key} . "\n";
  }
}

for my $t (1..$threads) {                                                                          
  push @threads, threads->create(\&test, $t);
}                                                                                                  
# Дожидаемся окончания работы всех потоков
foreach my $t (@threads) {
  $t->join();
}


exit(0);
```

Comment: первое что выдал гугл по запросу "perl multithreading": https://habrahabr.ru/post/128477/  отличный пример, правда у них массив а не хеш. Но никто не мешает работать с расшаренной переменной как с обычной. Кстати - удалить элемент хеша можно с помощью delete

Comment: Привет @Mike , да я читал это, много всего, но как сделать для моих нужд - не вдупляю :( Плохой из меня, видимо, perl-программист.

Comment: И если добавить в функцию  `delete($hello{$key})` - всю работу делает первый поток, только как-то "криво", иногда слепляя строки и по-моему, дублируя их... видимо я что-то не понимаю, чего-то не учёл.

Comment: Да, я понял вашу проблему. сейчас попробую разобраться, никогда с потоками дела не имел :) на вскидку могу сказать, что переменную надо блокировать, что бы получить значение и удалить его...

Comment: @Mike Типа как-то наверно так http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23753538/how-to-write-a-multi-thread-perl-script-to-write-a-log-file я это давно нагуглил, но это же какая-то суровая жестятина, я думал это как-то проще можно сделать. Вообще я писал многопоточный скрипт 2 года назад, чтоб сеть сканить, но там я юзал "шерл" и в этот раз хотел сделать по-нормальному. В прошлый раз я в функции делал это `system("/usr/bin/nmap -p80 -PN -n -T5 --defeat-rst-ratelimit --nsock-engine select --open --min-parallelism 254 -oG - $ip| awk '/open/{print \$2}' >> $path");`

Comment: @user226699, отвлечённо: вкиньте уже `Data::Dumper` и откройте для себя `Data::Printer` :-)

Comment: нет, это не то. у вас основная проблема в функции keys. она строит независимый от самого хеша список ключей, вы получаете ключи на момент старта цикла, а не достаете значения по одному. И почему собственно хеш, а не массив

Comment: @PinkTux спсибо, я попробую! Просто раз в пятилетку юзаю перл и как-то не задавался вопросом как лучше смотреть что в переменных :)

Comment: @Mike да я не знаю почему массив хешей и почему перл вообще, я б на питоне написал, но тут на самом деле скрипт который до меня кто-то написал лет 6 назад длинной в 2к строк и мне надо его просто распараллелить. Я сначала хотел заюзать anyevent (Много раз его юзал, нормас модуль) но нет тех. возможности. Пардон, тут Остапа понесло)) Ответ на Ваш вопрос: Мне просто нужны key => value , а массив хешей для этого подходит как нельзя лучше. Ну-у-у, я думаю именно поэтому его юзал автор скрипта...

Comment: В этом массиве хешей на самом деле соответствия `host => ip`, я конечно могу попробовать сделать обычный массив `@hello` из только хостов и написать функцию резолвинга, но блин, лень :( Там просто миллион всего придётся тогда переписывать... И я в себя не верю, скорее всего это не вкатит...

Comment: Протестил с просто массивом. Забавно, почему тут работает: http://ideone.com/mZXgtc , а у меня на машине первый поток обрабатывает первый элемент и дохнет, а второй уже все остальные? Я ваще запутался 8D

Comment: Пардон, это я туплю, просто формат вывода другой видимо, я там поправил и всё сразу понял 8D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю на сколько оно рабочее на самом деле, отлаживать пришлось на ideone, потому как многопоточного perl под руками не оказалось...

```
use threads;
use threads::shared;
use Time::HiRes qw(usleep);

my $threads = 2;
my @threads;
my %hello : shared = (a,1,b,2,c,3,d,4);

sub test {
  my $num=shift;
  print "+ Thread $num started !.\n";

  while(1) {
    my ($key,$val);
      { # block for lock
         lock(%hello);
         $key=(keys %hello)[0];
         $val=$hello{$key};
         delete $hello{$key} if($key);
      }
    last unless $key;
    print "Thread $num: $key $val\n";
    usleep(100*int(rand(10)));
  }
}

for my $t (1..$threads) {                                                                          
  push @threads, threads->create(\&test, $t);
}                                                                                                  
# Дожидаемся окончания работы всех потоков
foreach my $t (@threads) {
  $t->join();
}


exit(0);
```

По крайней мере каждое из значений печатается по 1 разу. Пришлось использовать sleep иначе один поток успевал обработать все.

Основная идея: блокируем хеш, достаем один ключ, запоминаем значение, удаляем ключ, разблокируем хеш (явного снятия блока не предусмотрено, блокирока снимается по окончании блока кода). Кроме получения и удаления элемента при взятой блокировке ничего не делаем, работа происходит уже после снятия блокировки. Если этого не сделать то наши потоки будут выполнятся строго по очереди, а не одновременно.

Comment: O.O А чего это за сильное колдунство `my ($key,$val); { ... }` ?

Comment: @user226699 Фигурные скобки к my никакого отношения не имеют. Они сами по себе, они обрамляют синтаксический блок (блок не обязан начинаться всякими for/while). Этот синтаксический блок нужен что бы после него снялась блокировка, потому как она действует в пределах блока

Comment: Яснопонятно... не думаю что perl хьюман ридбл :) Как считаете, лучше делать через массив хешей или через обычный массив?

Comment: @user226699 от задачи зависит, если нужен быстрый доступ по осмысленным ключам - то хеш, а если просто очередь для работы - то массив. По крайней мере с массивом не нужны блокировки если использовать shift/pop. Да и если сейчас хеш - то может так и оставить что бы меньше переделывать. С другой стороны вытащить и удалить элемент надо быстро, а значит ниже по коду использовать $hash{$key} уже нельзя будет, элемент то удалили.

Comment: @user226699 Кстати, а что вы массивом хешей называете. В примере у вас просто хеш :)

Comment: ну если делать по-уму, то там вообще всё переписывать надо и делать это надо нормальному программисту, а не мне 8D Я вот эту штуку `%hello` называю массивом хешей :) В моём испорченном, закостенелом сознании, всё что хранит более одного значения "за раз" - массив :) И даже не спрашивайте откуда у меня в мозгу такая ересь, сам не знаю :) Ладно, Вы мне очень помогли. Спасибо Вам за кучу потраченного времени на меня и этому ресурсу. Классно когда в одном месте очень много умных людей :)

Comment: @user226699 Если помог, поставьте зеленую галочку под рейтингом ответа :)  Ну да, много значений ... действительно почему бы не назвать массивом, логично ... Одна беда, вас могут не понять ибо это хеш :) Ох уж эта терминология

Answer (score 1):

Набросал было на `Mojo::IOLoop`, но плюнул и таки сорвался на `AnyEvent` :-) Дополнительно умеет ограничивать обработку (запуск максимум M одновременных воркеров в N секунд). Хотя, если говорить об ограничениях, то можно было бы и не так. Но это уже совсем из другой области.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
use Modern::Perl;
use AnyEvent;
use Const::Fast;
use Data::Lock qw/dlock dunlock/;
use Data::Printer;

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
const my $MAX_WORKERS => 10;     # количество одновременных запросов (M)
const my $INTERVAL    => 1.0;    # интервал (N)
const my $DEBUG       => 1;
my %data = map { $_ => $_ } ( 1 .. ($MAX_WORKERS * 10) );
my %result;
my %dups;

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
while (keys %data) {
    my $tstart         = AnyEvent->time();
    my $cv             = AnyEvent->condvar();

    # формируем $MAX_WORKERS одновременных запросов:
    for ( 0 .. $MAX_WORKERS ) {
        my $id = $_;

        dlock(%data);
        my $key = ( keys %data )[0];
        if ($key) {
            $cv->begin();
            my $val = $data{$key};
            $dups{$key} = $val if $result{$key};
            $result{$key} = $val;
            say "[worker $id] $key => $val";
            delete $data{$key};
            dunlock(%data);
            #
            # здесь делаем что нужно
            #
            $cv->end();
        }
        dunlock(%data);
    }
    $cv->recv();

    last unless keys %data;
    my $sleeping = $INTERVAL - ( AnyEvent->time() - $tstart );

    # слишком быстро - поспим:
    if ( $sleeping > 0 ) {
        printf( "sleeping for %.3f seconds...\n", $sleeping ) if $DEBUG;
        my $sleep = AnyEvent->condvar();
        my $timer = AnyEvent->timer( after => $sleeping, cb => $sleep );
        $sleep->recv();
    }
    else {
        say 'no sleeping needed' if $DEBUG;
    }
}

say 'Done, dups:';
p %dups;
```