# shared hash и threads

Tags: многопоточность, perl, share

```
sub get_data
{
    use threads;
    use threads::shared;

    my %result:shared;   
    my $cnt:shared = 10;    

    my $page_counter = sub {
                            my $nb = shift;                    

                            while ($cnt > 0) {  
                                my $n = $cnt; 

                                print "Thread # $nb treats string number $n\n";       
                                my $data = 'запрос к серверу';        
                                my @tmp = @{$data};                                                            
                                foreach (my $i = 0; $i <= $#tmp; $i++) {                                    
                                    # проблемное место, хочу писать в расшаренный хеш                             
                                    %result = (%result, $tmp[$i] -> {'id'} => shared_clone([$tmp[$i] -> {'name1'}, $tmp[$i] -> {'name2'}]));                                    
                                }
                                $cnt--;
                            }
                          };

    for my $t (1..10) { 
        threads -> create($page_counter, $t);
    }

    foreach my $t (threads -> list) {
        if ($t -> tid && !threads::equal($t, threads -> self)) {
            $t -> join();
        }
    }

    return \%result;   
}
```

Хочу собрать данные в хэш из нескольких потоков, не понимаю, как правильно это делается. Маны читал, пока не доходит. Примерный код выше.

**UPD**. Добавил shared_clone, результат меня удовлетворяет.

Comment: А какие сложности возникают, что тут не работает ? Хотя вам бы не помешало бы блокировать хеш на время записи и главное, вы присвоением `%result = ()` создаете полностью новый хеш, это очень медленно и думаю сбивает шаринг. добавляйте один элемент `$result{ $tmp[$i] -> {'id'} } = [...]`. О блокировках http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/586880/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D1%85%D1%8D%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B9/586892#586892

Comment: А еще что то не видно когда потоки завершаться т.к. цикл бесконечный и выхода из него не предусмотрено.

Comment: Потоки завершаются по счетчику. В примере не отразил - потерял, когда выдирал лишнее, вероятно. С этим проблем нет. Насчет того, что создается новый хэш - всегда пишу со включенным strict-ом и немного не понял про создание нового хэша. Разве тут не присваивание хэша самому себе? Попробую разобраться с блокировками. Нельзя ли коротко принцип действия lock?

Comment: Вы сначала разворачиваете хеш в список, а потом создаете новый хеш из этого списка. Эмм... что значит принцип действия lock... ну он блокирует хеш и другой поток в это же время пытающийся взять лок приостанавливается и ждет пока первый закончит работать с хешем. хотя на добавление одного значения лок скорее всего ни к чему. это если вам надо прочитать и модифицировать или выполнить атомарно несколько изменений тогда он точно необходим

Comment: я бы кстати записал бы вообще в виде `$result{ $_->{id} } = [ $_->{name1}, $_->{name2} ] for @{$data};`

Comment: Я поэкспериментирую с таким видом записи и если найду его для себя удобным, возьму на вооружение. Собственно, сервер отдает мне json с кучей всякой инфы, откуда я выбираю пару-другую полей, заворачиваю в структуру, удобную для дальнейшей работы и возвращаю. @tmp тут для того, чтобы не тащить за собой запись вида $data -> [0] -> {'code'} -> [1] -> ...

Comment: Проблема в том, что запись в хэш, приведенная в моем примере, дает на выходе хэш с одним-единственным значением, при том, что каждый поток должен добавить по 100 значений. Если я пишу вместо хэша в плоский файл - все работает на ура, отсюда предположение о том, что shared hash используется не верно. Вообще, вы подкинули мне достаточно пищи для размышления, проверить варианты смогу завтра.

Comment: При записи `$result{ $_->{id} } = [ $_->{name1}, $_->{name2} ] for @{$data};` получаю **Invalid value for shared scalar at test.pm line 281**. 
Сделал так `$result{ $_->{id} } = shared_clone([ $_->{name1}, $_->{name2} ]) for @{$data};`. Если в такой записи нет ничего криминального, то я разобрался, спасибо.

Comment: Да, я тупанул, он считает `$result{X}` скаляром и присваивать ему сам массив как то нехорошо. `shared_clone()` - почему бы и нет он вернет ссылку на массив и она отлично присвоится скаляру. В моем варианте  было бы правильным сразу сказать, что элемент %result это массив и потом ему присваивать список (не массив, в круглых скобках) `@{ $result{ $_->{id} } } = ( $_->{name1}, $_->{name2} )`

Comment: И теоретически можно пойти дальше и сократить запись выборки нескольких элементов из хеша в виде среза: `@{ $result{ $_->{id} } } = @{ $_ } {'name1','name2'}` такой синтаксис полезен когда надо получить список многих элементов хеша по ключам. Но в данном случае разыменование `@{ $_ }` мне кажется каким то не очевидным и путает при взгляде на код. но тут уж кому как нравится

Comment: Да, изначально разыменование выглядело, как в последнем варианте, перешел к более понятному для себя. Спасибо за помощь, понимание некоторых моментов пришло во время обсуждения. Думаю, вопрос исчерпан.