# Нужна ли блокировка переменной (lock VARIABLE) при использовании threads::shared?

Tags: многопоточность, perl

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use threads;
use threads::shared;
my @arr : shared;

@arr = (1..300);

my $total = 10;

my @build;
for (0..$total-1){
    $build[$_] = threads->create(\&thread);
}
for(@build){
  $_->join;
}

sub thread{
    while(@arr){

        # {lock(@arr); $a = shift @arr;}

        my $a = shift @arr;

        sleep rand 5;

        print "$a\n";

    }
}
```

perl (v5.26.1) build 2601

Нужен ли [lock](http://perldoc.perl.org/threads/shared.html#lock-VARIABLE)? По идее, должны быть повторы элементов, но этого не наблюдается. Возможно это зависит от версии perl, т.к. в старой повторы были.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15636329/is-it-required-to-lock-shared-variables-in-perl-for-read-access

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15636329/is-it-required-to-lock-shared-variables-in-perl-for-read-access

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/633125/shared-hash-%d0%b8-threads

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/586880/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D1%85%D1%8D%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B9